# possible number of arrangements for a group of 6 words

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many ways (possible combinations without repetition) can we arrange these words?

ServiceInfo, TokenInfo, AccountInfo, DeviceInfo, LocationCoarseInfo, LocationPreciseInfo

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: You seem to be using the words in non-standard ways. Perhaps you're looking for the number of permutations of these words?